# Access Fluid extbase variables globally in another extension

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have a view assigned and used for breadcrumbs in one extension

```
    $this->view->assign('breadcrumbs', $breadcrumbs);
```

I'd like to access and use this variable outside the scope of the extension, so in another extension.

However I cannot find the variable when I do a extbase variable dump from the latter extension. Can I somehow make this variable accessable globally for the installation?

Is there some typoscript setup I am missing? Something equal to partialRootPaths for variable?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like that available for variables. the only thing I can imagine what would work is use a ViewHelper for that.

Comment: Thatd quickly make for a lot of duplicate code outside extensions then :(

Comment: If I use a partial located in that extension it would still not work?

Comment: by using `<f:render partial="fo" arguments={_all} />` all variables are handed to that partial as well.

Comment: Georg, I did try that, and it does indeed pass all arguments.. But I need to seperate them, and it makes no sense its available there when I cannot see it using debug: {_all}